# Several div elements for Schema.org Product?

Tags: html, schema.org

I've got a web page I'd like to setup Schema.org `Product` for, however the data I need for this is spread throughout the page.

Is there a way to have multiple `div` elements for the Schema.org `Product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Microdata you can use the itemref attribute:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemref

It allows you to refer to other elements on the page by their ids. What's inside those ideas have their itemprops included in the current scope. Here's a simple example.

```
<div id="janedoeimage" >
   <img src="janedoe.jpg" itemprop="image" />
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="janedoeimage">
    <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
```

This parses to the following JSON:

```
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "type": [
            "http://schema.org/Person"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "image": [
              "http://example.com/janedoe.jpg"
            ],
            "name": [
              "Jane Doe"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

RDFa Lite may soon be getting a way to do prototyping which is similar to Microdata's itemref attribute. I'm not sure where this currently is in the process, though.